# How to check if the destination line has answered a call with porsip sdk on android

Tags: android, portsip

With the Portsip manual, it says com.portsip.OnPortSIPEvent.onInviteAnswered will be triggered if the remote party answered the call. But what i've got so far is when A make a call to B, the onInviteAnswered callback is just immediately triggered on the A side without knowing that B has actually answered the call yet.

Or this is the expected behavior please help.

Answer (score 0):

All the callback events of PortSIP VoIP SDK is triggered depending on the SIP message received from remote side only. In your case, if the onInviteAnswered is triggered,  it  must mean that the SDK has received 200 OK from server/remote side.

What's the SIP server/PBX you're using? Would you please run the WireShark to capture the SIP messages on your server during your testing, and  export the captured messages as wireshark file and send to us by support@portsip.com (just filter it by "sip" filter)?

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the guide you provide. I'm doing the test with WireShark and will send the captured messages to you.